# ¿Cómo tener una variable global sin reseteo en API Rest c#?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, webapi

Tengo un API Rest en C# que ya funciona, y me surge la necesidad de tener un objeto con datos que sea constante para cada petición. El problema surge en que este objeto debo llenarlo de varias consultas de mi Base de Datos, la idea de tener un objeto global para cada petición es no realizar estas consultas por cada petición que se hace al API (dado que la información consultada es constante), sino poder tenerla siempre disponible desde el inicio del API.

He estado leyendo sobre posibilidades de hacerlo en el `Global.asax.cs` en el `Application_Start()` del API pero no tengo idea de cómo lograrlo y mantener la variable como tipo variable de sesión o similar en la cache de la aplicación (no del cliente).

Necesito un ejemplo de esta persistencia que necesito, para que al arrancar el API (`Application_Start`) se llene la variable, en este caso mi objeto, con la información que necesito y que en cada petición ya pueda usar esta variable sin tener que volver a ejecutar las consultas cada vez.

Comment: Una **variable o clase estática** persiste en todo el ámbito de la aplicación, en tu caso un Web API Rest.

Comment: Sé que es persistente, pero no su contenido, si inicializo por ejemplo una variable en 2, y en el `Application_Start` le digo que ahora sea 5, cuando hago la petición, la variable no tengo como leerla y para mi sigue siendo 2, entonces no sé como leerla en el controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo mejor se adapta a tu situación es el uso de una clase [Singleton](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton), que por definición significa:

> garantizar que una clase solo tenga una instancia y proporcionar un
>   punto de acceso global a ella.

Te pongo un ejemplo sencillo en C#  para que lo veas.

Según lo que comentas tu clase Singleton tendría un aspecto similar a este:

```
    public class Global
    {
        private static readonly Global instancia = new Global();

        public static tuObjeto objeto;

        static Global()
        {

        }

        private Global()
        {
            // aqui iria todo el acceso a datos que necesitas
            objeto = CargaDesdeBD();
        }

        public static Global Instancia
        {
            get
            {
                return instancia;
            }
        }
    }
```

Para inicializarla, en el `Application_Start()` tendrías que poner algo como lo siguiente:

```
var instancia = Global.Instancia;
```

Pùedes usar la variable `objeto` en cualquier parte de tu código (ya que es estática) de la siguiente manera:

```
Global.objeto
```

De este modo, cuando se llame a `Application_Start()` la clase comprueba si está instanciada (si existe en memoria), si no es así se inicializa y se realiza la carga de la variable `objeto`, en caso contrario se devuelve la misma clase instanciada y no se realiza de nuevo la carga de datos.

El uso de una clase Singleton tiene múltiples variaciones dado que al fin y al cabo su definición se basa en un patrón y no una regla como tal, puedes buscar mas infomación si lo necesitas thread-safe, etc.

Comment: Dejame probarla, intentaré crear algo similar en mi API y ver que no se estén ejecutando las consultas por cada petición

Answer (score 1):

Aunque hay varias opciones para eso: variables estáticas, singletons, etc. desde mi punto de vista tu necesidad encaja en lo que sería una caché.

Veo siempre mejor tener una caché con un mecanismo de actualización definido que dejar los datos en variables estáticas. Puedes poner por ejemplo que la caché se invalide cuando pasen 5 min.

Por ejemplo, puedes añadir el System.Runtime.Caching y usar una clase de utilidad como esta:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Caching;


public static class MemoryCacher
{
    public static object GetValue(string key)
    {
        MemoryCache memoryCache = MemoryCache.Default;
        return memoryCache.Get(key);
    }

    public static bool Add(string key, object value, DateTimeOffset absExpiration)
    {
        MemoryCache memoryCache = MemoryCache.Default;
        return memoryCache.Add(key, value, absExpiration);
    }

    public static  void Delete(string key)
    {
        MemoryCache memoryCache = MemoryCache.Default;
        if (memoryCache.Contains(key))
        {
            memoryCache.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

La idea es comprobar si existe ese dato en la caché. Si existe lo utilizas y, si no existe, lo vas a buscar a la base de datos y lo insertas en la caché.